# git の tree-ish を tree object の id に変換するには？

Tags: git

git の tree-ish には、いくつかの書式があります。

```
develop
develop^
HEAD
develop:some-dir
```

これらを引数に、 tree object の id そのものを取得するにはどうしたらいいですか？

背景: `git commit-tree` が tree-ish ではなく、 tree object の id でないと動いてくれなかったので。

Comment: `git rev-parse HEAD` とか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@yas さんや @metropolis さんの答えを参考にすると、自分が欲しかったものは次でした。

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
    echo "usage: $0 treeish" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi

treeish="$1"

case $(git cat-file -t "${treeish}") in
    commit)
        git cat-file -p "${treeish}" |
            sed -n 1p |
            awk '{print $2}'
    ;;
    tree)
        git rev-parse "${treeish}"
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

`git cat-file` で出力できるようです。

```
git cat-file -p HEAD
```